# Updating cursor with values from txt file

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm trying to update fields with `updateCursor`, but it doesn't work at all.
I've worked with `updateCursor` before many times but this time - no success.

I have a feature class (`frameBoundaryBeforeAT`) in which I need to update his fields according to a text file. I extracted the name and other parameters from the text and append them into a list.

I'm going through the list and i compare between the name in the `fc` and the name in the `list= (if str(row[10]) == info_extract[0])`
and if it's the same name, I want to update the other fields in `fc`.
The loop is fine, it matches the names, the if is working (I've checked it with a simple print - *print "it's a match"*) but when it's come to updating the field  - nothing happened.

If I delete the `if` and just update the fields with some random characters it works, but the if statement is ok so what is the problem?

I tried to print after the line: `row[0] = info_extract[1]`, just to see what it does and I can see the name that I wanted, but when I open the `fc` I see empty fields.

```
db = r"D:\Work work work\A\arc\per_day_GDB\Flight_020721.gdb"
txt = r"D:\Work work work\A\arc\Data_for_GDB\Best_fit_eop\noa.txt"

txt_list = extract_list_from_txt(txt)
frameBoundaryBeforeAT = db + "//frameBoundaryBeforeAT"
fieldnames = ["Frame","Camera","Easting","Northing","MSL_Height","Omega","Phi","Kappa","Date","Time","Feature_Name"]

for line in txt_list:
    info_extract = extract_info_from_list(line)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(frameBoundaryBeforeAT, fieldnames) as cursor:
         for row in cursor:
            if str(row[10]) == info_extract[0]:
                print "it's a match"
                row[0] = info_extract[1]
                row[1] = "DMCIIe_250"
                row[2] = info_extract[2]
                row[3] = info_extract[3]
                row[4] = info_extract[4]
                row[5] = info_extract[5]
                row[6] = info_extract[6]
                row[7] = info_extract[7]
                #Urow[8] = info_extract[8]
                row[9] = info_extract[9]
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: You've structured this code incorrectly. Use the text file to build a dictionary, then make *one* update pass with the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is highly inefficient because you're iterating over the entire shapefile for each line of your text file ! Maybe this is causing some issues.

As Vince said in his comment, create a dict with your txt file information and then iterate only one time with the cursor :

```py
db = r"D:\Work work work\A\arc\per_day_GDB\Flight_020721.gdb"
txt = r"D:\Work work work\A\arc\Data_for_GDB\Best_fit_eop\noa.txt"

txt_list = extract_list_from_txt(txt)
frameBoundaryBeforeAT = db + "//frameBoundaryBeforeAT"
fieldnames = ["Frame","Camera","Easting","Northing","MSL_Height","Omega","Phi","Kappa",
"Date","Time","Feature_Name"]

extracted_info = {}
for line in txt_list:
    # I suppose extract_info_from_list creates a list from a line of your txt file
    extracted = extract_info_from_list(line)
    extracted_info[extracted[0]] = extracted

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(frameBoundaryBeforeAT, fieldnames) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if str(row[10]) in extracted_info:
            print "it's a match : {}".format(row[10])
            info_extract = extracted_info[str(row[10])]
            row[0] = info_extract[1]
            row[1] = "DMCIIe_250"
            row[2] = info_extract[2]
            row[3] = info_extract[3]
            row[4] = info_extract[4]
            row[5] = info_extract[5]
            row[6] = info_extract[6]
            row[7] = info_extract[7]
            # Urow[8] = info_extract[8]
            row[9] = info_extract[9]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```